# SwiftUI - ProgressBar inside Live Activity

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, widgetliveactivity

I am trying to add a simple visual progress bar to my live activity on lock screen or in Digital Island but I can't find a way to trigger progress calculation update. Seems like Timer nor @State work inside of the live activity. Its weird because both native and public apps do use progress bars in activities that update more often then once a second even when apps are suspended and look super smooth.

Apple native timer app still animates smoothly when suspended

[image]

One of my favorite apps - Structured also managed to do it when suspended [image]

I tried already even adding Lottie animations to the activity :D

Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please also read the Apple Documentation and watch the appropriated videos from WWDC 22 (and WWDC 23 if writing for iOS 17).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently you are not allowed to make custom progress bars in the live activity or at least I didn't find a way to do so. iOS is limiting your abilities to trigger timers, loops and any logical methods to update the progress bar. The only way I found doing it is by using a native progress bar

```swift
ProgressView(
    timerInterval: countFrom...endDate,
    countsDown: false,
    label: { EmptyView() },
    currentValueLabel: { EmptyView() }
)
.progressViewStyle(.circular)
```

Comment: The pity thing is that you cannot even write your own progress view style. But yeah, it only supports native `ProgressView` and therefore works pretty much the same way you'd display an autoupdating timer – only via native `Text(date, style: .timer)` or `Text(timeInterval: startDate...endDate)`